# Why can't I connect to my rds aurora postgres v1 from outside its VPC?

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, amazon-vpc

I have an rds aurora postgres v1 depoyed on aws and have verified that the data-base's subnets are linked to a security group that allows traffic to and from 0.0.0.0/0, and that the subnets are associated to route table linked to an internet gateway. There is a network acl associated with the subnets but I have verified that the acl also allows traffic to and from 0.0.0.0/0 for all protocols and ports. I have set this up via the console so unfortunately I can't provide the terraform.

Connecting to the database from within the vpc works fine, but when I try to call it from my own computer I get a timeout:

```
.OperationalError: connection to server at "operational-postgresql-XXXX-dev.cluster-clzuz55wnzjg.XXXXXX.rds.amazonaws.com" (XXX.31.30.191), port 5432 failed: Operation timed out
    Is the server running on that host and accepting TCP/IP connections?
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: What do you mean by "v1"? Do you mean "Serverless V1"?

Comment: yes that's what I mean, sorry.